# H2 in memory database doesn't show tables created in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

i have H2 in memory database configured with spring boot in maven multi module environment.

Spring boot log says **Schema export complete**,i couldn't see any table getting created in h2 database.

**application.properties**

```
#spring h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

#Spring data JPA properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb:MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**Logs:**

```
2016-11-15 16:35:05.413  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-11-15 16:35:05.429  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-11-15 16:35:05.525  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-11-15 16:35:05.527  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-11-15 16:35:05.529  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-11-15 16:35:05.900  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-11-15 16:35:05.982  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2016-11-15 16:35:06.025  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-11-15 16:35:06.148  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-11-15 16:35:06.150  INFO 10288 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Can some One explain whats wrong with the configuration.

Comment: This is spring boot and doesn't require any XML files. Since it is auto configured.

Comment: would you show me your h2 datasource config class and logback\log4j config ?maybe there some wrong use in your code.

Comment: I don't have separate class,its a spring boot auto-configuration.

Comment: How do you check the content of the database? You may connect with another process if you use a TCP server (http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases).

Comment: @mcoolive,i am not able to view the content of any.I am assuming table is getting created since Schema export complete is being printed on the console.

Comment: @BeeNoisy,i have logback file filled with.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="trace"/>
</configuration>

Comment: Source Code:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gs6jstyf9755hzf/AABNdxlYEFehbzf_fx1ZLW9Aa?dl=0

Comment: I miss something, why do you think there is an issue in the schema exportation if logs are OK? When I have unknown issue with H2, I frequently change the configuration to be able to use the H2 web console. Sometimes the issue is quite different from what I imagine first :-)

Comment: Can you look at the source code please.i have tried every other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So,it is  a simple annotation which in-turn scans the entity classes.

Had it not been a multi module project,this annotation wasn't required.

Annotate the main class with @EntityScan("packageName");

Comment: This is not a good idea. It's just a work around. It should work without scanning the package where multiple entities reside. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841072/spring-boot-in-memory-database-h2-doesnt-loads-data-from-file-on-initialization .

Comment: When you group your source code with different packages you got to scan,unless you have a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

In this document:http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate

Says: You can output the schema creation by enabling the org.hibernate.SQL logger. This is done for you automatically if you enable the debug mode.

Here is the [debug model](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging-console-output)

> $ java -jar myapp.jar --debug

you can also specify `debug=true` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: Source code:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gs6jstyf9755hzf/AABNdxlYEFehbzf_fx1ZLW9Aa?dl=0

Comment: I will help to try to find answer. give me some times. And would you like to put your code to github? then we can change it\read it\modify it as a team.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i faced and i added below changes to resolve it,

i added below version for H2 dependencies in pom.xml

`<version>1.4.193</version>`

And added below configuration in properties file

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```