# Spring Boot in memory database H2 doesn't load data from file on initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have an issue with loading data into an in-memory database on application initialization. I have created **schema.sql** and **data.sql** files containing table structure and initial data.

**schema.sql :**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id          INT PRIMARY KEY,
  username    VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  password    VARCHAR(64) 
);
```

and **data.sql** :

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES
  (1, 'usr1', 'bigSecret'),
  (2, 'usr2', 'topSecret');
```

I am using `JpaRepository` for working with data layer:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

And I also configure **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=- 1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

But when I call

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
```

User entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String username;
  private String password;

  public User() {  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

I get an empty list, but I should get two pre-populated users from my in-memory H2 database. What's wrong with in memory database? 
Thanks.

Comment: where did you place those scripts?

Comment: I'm wondering if your URL is OK with the extra space `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=- 1;` => `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;`

Comment: can you show your `User` entity

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski I have placed scripts into /src/main/resources and it seems that they are read by application.

Comment: @alexbt I have removed space and there is the same result - no data extracted from file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always try to run those scripts per specification of h2, where you should add an INIT script in your connection url (being one of the options):

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/schema.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/data.sql'"
```

> This functionality is enabled via the INIT property. Note that
>   multiple commands may be passed to INIT, but the semicolon delimiter
>   must be escaped, as in the example below.

**Update**

Be aware that having these options in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=true
spring.datasource.initialize=true
```

may cause some clashing during startup. So you should always aim for one or the other, but never both at the same time. 
For simple cases just these alone are sufficient to auto build tables and reload after shutdown & startup

Comment: I have tried to add sql scripts (schema.sql and data.sql) to **INIT** in `spring.datasource.url` property at application.conf, but I got exception on application launching - telling that table is already created (_org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USERS" already exists; SQL statement_), and I think it is because of `spring.datasource.initialize=true`. So... it seems that **INIT** and `spring.datasource.initialize=true` won't work together. @Maciej Kowalski

Comment: The correct settings for **application.conf** to make it working with in memory database initialized with data are: `spring.datasource.initialize=true` `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` `spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver` `spring.datasource.username=sa` `spring.datasource.password=` and the most important, don't forget to disable Hibernate database initialization property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` because default value `create-drop` will removes all data from tables inserted before. And you will have empty tables.

Comment: yes, that spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto probably have gotten in the way. Glad it finally works for you.

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none is causing for me h2 not to create any table at all....

Comment: thanks @tyomka. your suggestion to set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none was key to make it working. It saved my time.

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure out why the insertion didn't work until I found that `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` default's value is `create-drop`. All the configurations may be right but if this property is not specifically declared, then the data will be deleted, as @tyomka said

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem when I added the following lines to the application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:schema.sql,classpath:data.sql
```